# Uniqueness of the uniform spherical distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $X,Y$ are random vectors on some (possibly different) probability spaces mapping to $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Suppose furthermore that

- $\|X\|=r>0$ for all realizations of the sample space on which $X$ is defined,
- $\|Y\|=r$,
- if $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $U X$ and $X$ have the same distribution, and
- if $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $U Y$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

I want to show that $X$ and $Y$ must generate the same Borel probability distribution on $\mathbb R^n$. That is, there is a unique uniform distribution on the surface of the $n$-dimensional sphere of radius $r$.

---

I tried showing that the characteristic functions corresponding to $X$ and $Y$ must coincide. In doing so, I managed to derive that if the characteristic function of $X$ is, say, $\varphi:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb C$, then the following must hold for any $t\in\mathbb R^n$ and any orthogonal matrix $U\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$: $$\varphi(t)=\varphi(U^{\mathsf T}t).$$ Any further hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Choose $U$ uniformly randomly and independent of $X$, then $UX$ conditionally on $U$ has the distribution of $X$ hence $UX$ has the distribution of $X$. But the distribution of $UX$ conditonally on $X$ is uniform on the sphere of radius $\|X\|$ and $\|X\|=r$ almost surely hence the distribution of $UX$ is uniform on the sphere of radius $r$. By identification, the distribution of $X$ is uniform on the sphere of radius $r$.

Comment: Thank you, @Did. I’ve been looking for a more detailed and rigorous argument. If you are interested, please consult my answer below.

Comment: The argument in my comment is concisely written but *fully detailed and completely rigorous*. Which step did you miss?

Comment: For instance, I’m not sure I understand how to operationalize choosing $U$ “uniformly randomly.” Should the columns of $U$ be uniformly distributed on the sphere? How can one ensure that $U$ is (almost) always orthonormal? There are quite a few i’s to dot and t’s to cross here...

Comment: The sphere of radius $r$ carries a uniform measure $\sigma_r^n$, assume that the distribution of $U$ is $\sigma_r^n/|\sigma_r^n|$. Any other i to dot or t to cross?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of uniqueness. It is a bit long, but the best I have found. Any feedback is more than welcome.

Let $$C\equiv\{x\in\mathbb R^n\,|\,\|x\|=r\}$$ denote the surface of the $n$-dimensional sphere of radius $r$. Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ denote the $n$-dimensional Borel probability measures generated by $X$ and $Y$, respectively. The assumptions on $X$ and $Y$ imply that
\begin{align*}
\mu(C)=&\,1\tag{$\spadesuit$},\\
\mu(U^{-1}(E))=&\,\mu(E)\quad\forall E\in\mathscr B^n\tag{$\clubsuit$}
\end{align*}
for any orthogonal transformation $U:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$, where $\mathscr B^n$ denotes the $n$-dimensional Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^n$. The analogous properties hold for $\nu$. In what follows let $$B(\varepsilon,x)\equiv\{y\in\mathbb R^n\,|\,\|x-y\|<\varepsilon\}$$ denote the ball of radius $\varepsilon>0$ around $x\in\mathbb R^n$.

Claims 1–4 below only use the properties ($\spadesuit$)–($\clubsuit$), so they remain true if $\mu$ is replaced with $\nu$.

**Claim 1:** *For any fixed $\varepsilon>0$, the balls $B(\varepsilon,x)$ have the same $\mu$-measure for any $x\in C$.*

*Proof:* If $x,y\in C$, then there exists an orthogonal transformation $U:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ such that $U(x)=y$ (see the answers to another question of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827981/existence-of-rotations-between-two-points)). It follows that $U^{-1}(B(\varepsilon,y))=B(\varepsilon,x)$ and the claim follows from ($\clubsuit$). $\quad\blacksquare$

**Claim 2:** *If $x\in C$ and $\varepsilon >0$, then $\mu(B(\varepsilon,x))>0$.*

*Proof:* Since $C\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in C}B(\varepsilon,x)$ and $C$ is compact, there exist some $m\in\mathbb N$ and $\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}\subseteq C$ such that $C\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^m B(\varepsilon,x_i)$. Therefore, $$1=\mu(C)\leq\sum_{i=1}^m\mu(B(\varepsilon,x_i)).$$ By Claim $1$, it follows that $$\mu(B(\varepsilon,x))\geq\frac{1}{m}>0$$ for any $x\in C$. $\quad\blacksquare$

Define a function $F:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ as $$F(\varepsilon)\equiv \mu(B(\varepsilon,x))\quad\text{for $\varepsilon>0$},$$ where $x\in C$ is arbitrary. By Claim 1, this function is well-defined and does not depend on the particular choice of $x\in C$, and by Claim 2, it assumes positive values. The corresponding function where $\mu$ is replaced with $\nu$ will be denoted as $G$.

**Claim 3:** *Let $E\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be any open set such that $E\cap C\neq\varnothing$. Then, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mu(E\cap B(n^{-1},x))}{F(n^{-1})}=1\quad\text{for any $x\in E\cap C$}.$$*

*Proof:* If $x\in E\cap C$, then for $n\in\mathbb N$ large enough, $B(n^{-1},x)\subseteq E$. $\quad\blacksquare$

Claim 3 continues to hold if $\mu$ is replaced with $\nu$ and $F$ with $G$.

**Claim 4:** *For any Borel set $E\in\mathscr B^n$ and $\varepsilon>0$, the indicator function $(x,y)\mapsto \mathbb I_{E\cap B(\varepsilon,x)}(y)$ from $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ is measurable.*

*Proof:* Clearly, $(x,y)\mapsto \mathbb I_E(y)$ is measurable, so it is sufficient to show that $(x,y)\mapsto\mathbb I_{B(\varepsilon,x)}(y)$ is measurable. But the value of this function is $1$ if and only if $\|x-y\|<\varepsilon$, which holds on an open subset of $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n$. $\quad\blacksquare$

Note that Claim 4 implies that the function $$x\mapsto \mu(E\cap B(\varepsilon,x))=\int_{y\in\mathbb R^n}\mathbb I_{E\cap B(\varepsilon,x)}(y)\,\mathrm d\mu(y)$$
from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ is measurable.

Now I will show that $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on open sets, which will imply that they agree on all Borel sets, completing the proof of uniqueness. This argument is based on Theorem 3.4 in [Mattila (1999, pp. 45–46)](https://books.google.com/books?id=RTQmlDw9r6gC&printsec=frontcover&hl=hu&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). Let $E\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be an open set. If $E\cap C=\varnothing$, then ($\spadesuit$) implies that $\mu(E)=\nu(E)=0$. Suppose, therefore, that $E\cap C\neq\varnothing$. Then, one has the following:
\begin{align*}
\nu(E)=&\,\nu(E\cap C)=\int_{x\in E\cap C}1\,\mathrm d\nu(x)=\int_{x\in E\cap C}\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{\mu(E\cap B(n^{-1},x))}{F(n^{-1})}\right\}\mathrm d\nu(x)\\
\leq&\,\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\{\int_{x\in E\cap C}\frac{\mu(E\cap B(n^{-1},x))}{F(n^{-1})}\mathrm d\nu(x)\right\}\\=&\,\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{1}{F(n^{-1})}\int_{x\in E\cap C}\int_{y\in E\cap C}\mathbb I_{E}(y)\mathbb I_{B(n^{-1},x)}(y)\,\mathrm d\mu(y)\,\mathrm d\nu(x)\right\}\\
=&\,\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{1}{F(n^{-1})}\int_{y\in E\cap C}\int_{x\in E\cap C}\mathbb I_{B(n^{-1},y)}(x)\,\mathrm d\nu(x)\,\mathrm d\mu(y)\right\}\\
\leq&\,\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{1}{F(n^{-1})}\int_{y\in E\cap C}\int_{x\in\mathbb R}\mathbb I_{B(n^{-1},y)}(x)\,\mathrm d\nu(x)\,\mathrm d\mu(y)\right\}\\
=&\,\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{1}{F(n^{-1})}\int_{y\in E\cap C}\nu(B(n^{-1},y))\,\mathrm d\mu(y)\right\}\\
=&\,\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{G(n^{-1})}{F(n^{-1})}\mu(E)\right\}\\
=&\,\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{G(n^{-1})}{F(n^{-1})}\right\}\mu(E).
\end{align*}
where I used Claims 1 and 3, Fatou’s lemma, Tonelli’s theorem, and measurability of the integrands follows from Claim 4. A symmetric argument reveals that $$\mu(E)\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{F(n^{-1})}{G(n^{-1})}\right\}\nu(E).$$ In particular, if one were to choose $E\equiv B(m^{-1},x)$ for some $x\in C$ and $m\in\mathbb N$, then the first of the two inequalities just derived implies (the division is legitimiate–see Claim 2) that $$\frac{G(m^{-1})}{F(m^{-1})}=\frac{\nu(E)}{\mu(E)}\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{G(n^{-1})}{F(n^{-1})}\right\}.$$ Since this true for all $m\in\mathbb N$, it follows that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{G(n^{-1})}{F(n^{-1})}\right\}\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{G(n^{-1})}{F(n^{-1})}\right\},$$ so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{G(n^{-1})\div F(n^{-1})\}$ exists (and is possibly infinite). Similarly, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{F(n^{-1})\div G(n^{-1})\}$ exists as well (in $\mathbb R\cup\{+\infty\}$).

Now, if either one of these two limits is infinite, then the other is $0$ and the two key inequalities on $\mu(E)$ and $\nu(E)$ imply that $\mu(E)=\nu(E)=0$, which is impossible if, say, $E=\mathbb R^n$. If both of these limits are finite and one of them vanishes, then the other limit is infinite, and it follows that $\mu(E)=\nu(E)=0$, which is, again, impossible. Therefore, both limits must be finite and positive, so that they are reciprocals of each other. Consequently
\begin{align*}
\mu(E)\leq&\,c\nu(E),\\
\nu(E)\leq&\,c^{-1}\mu(E)
\end{align*}
for some $c>0$ (universal across any open $E\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ meeting $C$). Letting $E=\mathbb R^n$, it immediately follows that $c=1$, which implies that $\mu(E)=\nu(E)$ for general $E\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ that is open and meets $C$. The proof is now complete.